# The second derivative of the composition with a product, $H(x)=h(h(x)h(x^2))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $$H(x)=h(h(x)h(x^2))$$

What is a second derivative of this function?

I got first derivative.
$$(h'(x)h(x^2)+2xh'(x^2)h(x))+h'(x)h(x^2)$$
Is it right?

Comment: nope.  what is ( f (g(x)  )  ' , again ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your function  $H(x)=h(g(x))$, where $g(x)=h(x)f(x)$ , with  $f(x)=h(x^2)$. Then using chain rule, the derivative is $$ H'(x)=h'(g(x))g'(x)$$ but  $$g'(x)=h'(x)f(x)+h(x)f'(x)= h'(x)h(x^2)+2xh(x)h'(x^2) $$Thus
$$ H'(x)=h'(h(x)h(x^2))[h'(x)h(x^2)+2xh(x)h'(x^2) ]$$ Similarly you can try for  the second derivative.